# How can I execute a function if the mouswheel is used while shift is pressed?

Tags: javascript

I want to a function (for simplicitly let's say an alert) if the mousewheel is used while the shift key is pressed.

Listening solely to the mousewheel is easy and

```
elem.addEventListener('mousewheel', Alerttest);

function Alerttest(){
alert('works');
 }
```

How can I achieve the same thing but only in the case that shift is presed at the same time? Naively, I tried

```
elem.addEventListener('mousewheel.shiftKey', Alerttest);

function Alerttest(){
alert('works');
 }
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to check if [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) property of the passed `KeyboardEvent` object `e` to the `Alerttest()` function is `true` or not.

The `KeyboardEvent.shiftKey` read-only property is a `Boolean` that indicates if the <kbd>shift</kbd> key was pressed (`true`) or not (`false`) when the event occurred.

**Demo:**
(*Click inside the textbox and press mouse-wheel + shift key and then only the log is displayed*)

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('mousewheel', Alerttest);

function Alerttest(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey)
    console.log('works', );
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
```